# Can't enable module output

Tags: magento-1.9, module

I currently have an issue with a module output. I am currently using v.1.9.3.4

The extension module in question is shown as "Disabled" however the configuration in the extension shows "Enabled".

I can enable the module but as soon as I press Save it returns back to disabled.

Even if I try to enable this using code or via the database it seems to automatically disable itself once the change has executed.

Anyone else had this issue?

Comment: after installing extension, did you logged out and logged in again in admin panel?

Comment: The extension has been installed and working for months, it has recently had some issues which lead to me discovering the Module disabled.

Comment: Is it a licensed module? Sometimes there is some code in module which disables the module if the license details are not correct or are expired.

Comment: Hello, yes it is a licensed extension, after completing some research with the development team last night we found that the extension is no longer available from the company it was purchased from so we are now thinking that the license is not registering.